# Why isn't Rspec reloading the contents of my database table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

An integration spec includes:

```
click_on "submit_order"
order = Order.last
binding.pry_remote
```

Why, then, is the following possible?

And how do I fix it?

```
From: /Users/steven/Dropbox/Testivate/spec/features/order_spec.rb @ line 44 :

    43:       order = Order.last
 => 44:       binding.pry_remote

[1] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1>)> order
=> nil
[2] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1>)> Order.last
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| id | company  | url      | comp1    | comp2    | comp3    | user_id | guest... | guest... | creat... | updat... |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1  | The Nile | http:... | http:... | http:... | http:... | 1       |          |          | 2014-... | 2014-... |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
1 row in set
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried:

```
Order.connection.reconnect!
```

No change.

**UPDATE II**

When you change the integration spec to read...

```
click_on "submit_order"
save_and_open_page
order = Order.last
```

...the Order table reloads correctly and order is the last Order.

But why?

There are no callbacks on Order or User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP `POST` operation is not synchronous with the database update, so your `Order.last` method call is likely getting completed before the database write has been completed.  You would "fix" this by awaiting some positive confirmation that the submission has been completed (e.g. redirect, flash message, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it by putting my `page.should have_content` before my `order = Order.last`. That forced the spec to wait.